# Do not play m3u8 with chrome cast android

Tags: android, chromecast, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, m3u8

I getting errors when try to play m3u8 : W/MediaControlChannel: received unexpected error: Invalid Request.
W/MediaQueue: Error fetching queue item ids, statusCode=2100,
statusMessage=null.

I don’t understand if the problem is with the server CORS or the if the error is in the android app.
Link - "https://cdn.dev.yomobile.xyz/test/hls/c35ce4c4-d8a9-49ea-98a3-b98f99d4b8d4/master.m3u8"

You can see projects with my code integration cast https://github.com/OlegKopeykin/chromecast-simple